# How to access instance member in static method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class called `ApiHandler` and it is a generic. Now I have declared two instance variable in that class and wants to access it on static method.
This is how I have tried so far

```
    public class ApiHandler<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public ApiHandler(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        #region Normal
        public static async Task<T> GetAsync(string url)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // can't access this `_configuration` here
                string baseUrl = _configuration.GetSection("BaseUrl").Value;

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44345/api/");

                // Get token from cookies here

                var responseTask = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return await responseTask.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Server error. Please contact administrator.");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Here I want to access that `_configuration` variable inside `GetAsync` method which is a static method.
How can I achieve this
Please help me out!!!

Comment: Change your method signature to `GetAsync(ApiHandler<T> apiHandler, string url)` and pass the ApiHandler object in. Otherwise, it's not possible.

Comment: You would need to pass in an instance of your class into the static method.

Comment: Does your method need to be static? If not remove the `static` keyword. Otherwise you have to pass an instance of `IConfiguration` *or* pass an instance of `ApiHandler<T>`

Comment: You don't use `baseUrl` anywhere, so why do you need it? Do you need to set `client.BaseAddress` to that? Either make the `_configuration` static (which might imply that the entire class should be `static`), or make `GetAsync` an instance method.

Comment: Since `static` is global, consider this: you create two instances of ApiHandler, each with _a different_ `IConfiguration`. If the static method could access the instance field `_configuration`, how would it know which one to choose? It couldn't. That's (partly) why you either need to make the `GetAsync` method an instance method (remove `static`), or pass an instance of `ApiHandler` to it.

Comment: Also read [this article](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) about how you're using `HttpClient`, and the [older article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).